# Global var not getting value inside the ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Look my code:

I am using Jamal framekwork.

```
Event: {
        getEvents: function(){
            var events;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: anchor("Events/getEvents"),
                success: function(data) {   
                    if(data){
                        events = data;
                        console.log(events);
                    }
                }   
            }); 

            console.log(events);
            return events;
        }
    }
```

The first Output is:

```
{"0":{"id":"1","title":"title","description":"comment"},"1":{"id":"2","title":"title2","description":"comment2"}}
```

The second Output:
Undefined

If var events is a Global, why cant I set the value inside the ajax function and get the value after?

Jamal is breaking something?

Comment: Are you sure the second call worked? If you don't go through your success function, `events` is never assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because variable:

```
var events;
```

Is initialized in callback function - ajax call is asynchronous if you put:

```
console.log(events);
```

right after ajax call variable isn't assigned (it'll be somtime - but you don't know exacly when) - all logic need to be in callback.

Also you can make ajax call synchronous by setting: `async : false` then your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function you pass to ajax() is asynchronous. So execution arrives at the bottom call to console.log() *before* the success function is called. The success function is called when the server responds to your AJAX request.